# RegEx for text field with max length 140 with white Space

Tags: asp.net

I have Problem with my RegEx   it allow me to enter any text but when I have white space it throw error.what I have text field to enter summary and the summary  is lenght is 140 with white space my RegEx    `[\w\n\r]{0,140}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `[\w\n\r\t ]{0,140}`

That includes tabs and spaces as well.

Answer (score 1):

Or, more succinctly, `[.\n]{0, 140}`. The `.` operator will match any character except new lines (`\n`), hence the grouping.

If you're using .Net to do the RegEx matching, then you don't need `\n` when called like this:

```
Match m = Regex.Match("some string", @".{1, 140}", RegexOptions.SinglelLine);
```

HTH.